# How to use the Windows 8 boot screen with a keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot

[image]

The 'Choose an operation system' screen on Windows 8 allows you to use the cursor keys to choose between the different operating systems, but I couldn't find a way to select:

```
'Change defaults or choose other options'
```

with a keyboard.

I can use the mouse, but what if I don't have one?

In this case, the second OS is Server Core which does not need a mouse.

Comment: What is wrong with `Tab` key? Or you can press arrow keys as well.

Comment: Arrow keys? Your keyboard has them right?

Comment: @PratyushNalam cursor keys = arrow keys , so he has tried that .

Comment: whoops. in that case, `tab` should work

Comment: @PratyushNalam check my answer, and for your information <kbd> tag doesn't work for comment.

Comment: oops i put the same answer. Didn't see yours. And yeah realised kbd doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key which is working like a charm, while arrow keys didn't do the trick for me. So <kbd>Tab</kbd> key does the job as it do always inside the Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked my own Samsung RC512 with the windows-8 Boot screen. I seem to be having no issues at all with Arrow keys or the tab.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egi5IL5zDes&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

To select the operating system, use the  <kbd>up</kbd>  and <kbd>down</kbd> arrows, to tell the computer to actually boot into the selected operation system press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.